# How to use filter.AdditionalColumns to get the structure group id for every page in Tridion

Tags: web8

The current code fetches all the pages from the Root Structure Group as XML.
But in the page XML Elements, I would also need the parent Structure Group Information for the page.

Filter filter = new Filter();
filter.Conditions["ItemType"] = 64;     
filter.Conditions["Recursive"] = true;
result = rootSg.GetListItems(filter);

Is there any way to use filter.AdditionalColumns and fetch the information.

Comment: I would suspect that the additional columns that are supported will depend on the list method for which the Filter is used - have you referred to the APU documentation? Perhaps you can enhance your question (and help others to answer it in a few simple steps): 

(1) Include an example of the output to which you refer, 

(2) include the code that retrieves the list in the first place, 

(3) document what you've already tried/read?